# React-Router 404 solution working on dev but not on aws

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-router

I'm trying to avoid the `404 page` in my `react js` app in production. In `local host` the solution I had worked `(path="*")`, but when I `deploy` to `aws` it doesn't. This is are my routes:

```
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
<Router onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)} history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={k.App}>
        <IndexRoute component={k.Home}/>
        <Route path="/signin" component={k.SignIn}/>
        <Route path="/signup" component={k.SignUp}/>
        ...
        <Route path="*" component={k.NotFound}/>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Apparently the server is looking for the specific file, and how this is a single-page app it throws the 404. How can I solve this in the client side?

As well, when I refresh any specific page, I get a 404. I guess the problem is the same.

Thanks!

`react-router v2.8.1`
`react v15.3.2`

Comment: Since you are using browserHistory, this issue might have to do with your load balancer. The 404 page you get is from what? Your hosting provider? Try using hashHistory and see how it goes.

Comment: the 404 is from `aws` I guess. I get this: `404 Not Found nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)`

Comment: Then the problem is with load balancing. You should use hashHistory if that isn't a problem to you. Otherwise, you will have to deal with the load balancing issue.

Comment: hash history would mess my urls.. 

I've seen some solutions for this problem without messing with load balancing, but they didn't work for my app.